# Compiling Havok demos

Tags: c++, compilation, havok

I've downloaded and extracted the [Havok demos](http://software.intel.com/sites/havok/), but the project has dependency on a folder:

`$(HAVOK_SDKS_DIR)/win32/dx/Include`

But it didn't set up a HAVOK_SDKS_DIR (there is no installer), and I can't find a win32/dx directory *anywhere* in the extracted Havok package.

How can I get the demo files to build?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by simply REMOVING all references to $(HAVOK_SDKS_DIR) from the project settings.  You don't need it.